# Sharepoint 2016 installation with powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2016, commandlet

I tried installing sharepoint with wizard and autospinstaller both successfully. But now i want to install with only powershell via commands. But i am unable to find them or any good tutorial that can help me.

I will be thankfull for any link, code or advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just google it: `Sharepoint 2016 installation with powershell -AutoSPInstaller`.

First result: http://www.luisevalencia.com/2016/09/25/installing-sharepoint-server-2016-with-powershell/